# how to be sure delegation has been included?

Tags: delegation, staking

I would like to know if I delegated correctly. So far, I think I had delegated but I have not gotten any rewards.

How can I be sure that delegation request has been included? How can I confirm if my delegation are included in the cycle snapshot with the chosen baker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply enter your address into here to see future payouts. https://baking-bad.org/

Answer (score 3):

First you have to find out the snapshot# with RPC:

```
snapshotnum = chains/main/head/context/raw/json/cycle/CYCLE#>/roll_snapshot
```

Then you get the level that snapshot was. heres how its done in python, showing the constants that are used:

```
snapshotlevel = ((<CYCLE> - constants['preserved_cycles'] - 2) * constants['blocks_per_cycle']) + ((int(snapshotnum) + 1) * constants['blocks_per_roll_snapshot']))
```

Then from that level you just RPC to see what all accounts were delegated at the time of the snapshot:

```
chains/main/head/context/delegates/<YOUR DELEGATE PKHASH>
```

The list displayed will include your delegate pkhash (if it did make it into the snaphsot) along with anyone else delegated to your pkhash (if they also made it into the snapshot).

Comment: Any possibility to do this with the ledger live app and a web browser, without any coding?

Comment: @kerner1000 Yes, use a website like https://tzstats.com/ Enter the address of your baker, click the tab 'Delegations' and make sure you are listed. Remember that with any delegation, there is a minimum 20 day waiting period before the baker "sees" your delegation and usually a further 15 day waiting period before receiving your first rewards.